# Get the position (x,y) of the first character of the text within a text box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, position, point

How to convert the first character index within the textbox to the x,y coordinates in WPF ie basically I need the point loaction of the first character of the text within a textbox in WPF.I am capturing the x,y coordinates of the textbox wrt image displayed on the window screen in wpf
`UIElement container = (MainImage) as UIElement; System.Windows.Point relativeLocation = textboxinsert.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), container);`
But unaware to do it for text within a textbox in wpf.Any pointers would be really helpful?

Comment: you can use these https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx

Comment: You need to be more specific... Why do you need the coordinates of the first character, and what do you want to do with it, is this because of margins and paddings or something like that. because ironically enough, this sounds like an an X,Y problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @styx  GetPositionFromCharIndex works only in winforms .How to achieve it in wpf

Comment: @Michael Randall I am trying to insert a text over an image.I need the x,y coordinates of the first character within a textbox  so that I can draw it on the image.I am able to capture the coordinates of top left corner of the textbox but not the text.Margin,padding all set to 0 .Any suggestions would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to find the position of the first appearance, you will be fine with `TextBox.Text.IndexOf('x');`.

If you need to row too, you will need to make a difference between the lines that are broken because of the size of the textbox and the ones that are there because the user has pressed Enter.

You can do it by using a MemoryStream and a StreamReader.

Comment: hmm thats kinda what i was thinking of, Thumbs Up

Comment: @agent_Orange : Thanks for the response but i dont need the index as clearly mentioned I need to get the X,Y coordinates of the character within atext box in wpf

Comment: @krishnaa please see the 2nd and 3rd paragraph of my answer.

You can load the Text into a MemoryStream and the with StreamReader.ReadLine(); loop through the lines.

But please be aware of linebreaks that are only there because of the size of the textbox. They will not be noticed.

Comment: @krishnaa hmm can you tell me , you want x and y co ordinates but with reference of what? ie you wana know where that character is on destop screen?

Comment: @Agent_Orange -  I can capture the (x,y) of the top left corner of the text box wrt to the image displayed.
`UIElement container = (MainImage) as UIElement;
                        System.Windows.Point relativeLocation = textboxinsert.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), container); `.
But I need the x,y of the first character within the textbox